# Cycle accuracy through the use of a microtable for an 8 bit CPU emulation?

Tags: c, unix, gcc

I'm in the process of writing a 8 bit cpu emulator and currently have a jump table for different opcodes. I want to move this over to be cycle accurate and was wondering what the best approach would be in implementing a microtable?

I was thinking of something akin to the following:

```
//PSEUDO
static int (*microtable[][])(cpu *t_cpu) = {
        {FETCH_OP, FETCH_OPERAND, DO_JMP, BURN_CYCLE},
        {FETCH_OP, FETCH_OPERAND, DO_ADD, NIL},
};
```

Where each row is indicative of an OP, and each cycle is defined by an array of operations.

As an example the JMP instruction (first row) would take 3 cycles if it were to occur on the same page, otherwise 4 cycles by running the BURN_CYCLE.

This is to be driven by an external function that is set to execute at a certain clock rate, So essentially I will be assigning/referencing the micro-ops from the table on the fly during execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain operation of the JMP instruction -- as the conditional logic you're describing has to go somewhere, either in the table or in code.  Ideally, you'd use one or the other, rather than both.  For both Z80 and 6502 the longer branch instructions have different opcodes than the shorter branches so the table approach would work, I would think.  If that weren't the case, to use the table, you'd have to put conditional logic capabilities into the steps of the table for some opcodes, meaning the table's steps are more detailed.

Comment: @Erik Eidt, that's exactly right, I was thinking of having the conditional logic within the steps them self (as oposed to having a step in the table for the conditional logic). And would change the call order. I haven't exactly fleshed this out, but would this be appropriate? Or is there a better way? -thanks

Comment: I.e have the logic within the DO_JMP function ptr to determine whether to run BURN_CYCLE or not

Comment: That should work, so introduce different kinds of steps as needed, almost like microcode.  Then steps will tell you when the instruction is completed or if branching in the step sequence is needed, so they'll need to return some state to the step controller.

Comment: Cheers! I wasn't sure if this was ok or typical of what one would do in this instance. Thanks!